# open excel file with xlsx.js by path

Tags: javascript, excel, xlsx, arraybuffer

Hi i want to open excel file with xlsx extension with xlsx.js library.
I can open file by html input but i want to open it by using file path.

I have this code extracted from xlsx.js demo:

```
function handleFile(e) {
    rABS = false;
    use_worker = false;

    console.log(e);

    var files = e.target.files;


    var f = files[0]; {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var name = f.name;
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            if (typeof console !== 'undefined')
                console.log("onload", new Date(), rABS, use_worker);

            var data = e.target.result;
            console.log("target result >>>>>>>>> " + e.target.result);
            if (use_worker) {
                xw(data, process_wb);
            } else {
                var wb;
                if (rABS) {
                    wb = X.read(data, {
                            type : 'binary'
                        });
                } else {
                    var arr = fixdata(data);
                    wb = X.read(btoa(arr), {
                            type : 'base64'
                        });
                }
                process_wb(wb);
            }
        };
        if (rABS)
            reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
        else
            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
    }
}
```

I want something like this:

```
var file = new File([""],"C:\\Users\\PalFS\\Downloads\\Fiverr_Example_List (1).xlsx");

var data = file;
```

How to do this or how can i convert this file into arraybuffer like it is returned from, var data = e.target.result;.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag at chrome, chromium with  `XMLHttpRequest` , `.responseType` set to `"arraybuffer"` to retrieve `.xlsx` file from local filesystem as `ArrayBuffer`; set `new File()` data to returned `ArrayBuffer`. Second parameter at [`new File()`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#file-constructor) constructor should set the `.name` property of created file.

Launch `/path/to/chrome --allow-file-access-from-files`

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // may be necessary to escape path string?
  request.open("GET", "C:\\Users\\PalFS\\Downloads\\Fiverr_Example_List (1).xlsx");
  request.responseType = "arraybuffer";
  request.onload = function () {
     // this.response should be `ArrayBuffer` of `.xlsx` file
     var file = new File(this.response, "Fiverr_Example_List.xlsx");
     // do stuff with `file`
  };
  request.send();
```